Generate BPMN with the http or rest connector using java library or Camunda library for Camunda
Trying to generate a BPMN diagram, even a basic one with start event, end event and some service tasks from which we can call a rest api and consume the api response. Is there any Java libraries or API's available that would help me achieve this. Have searched around a lot but could not find any suitable. Any help would be appreciated.

Please let me know if anything is required at my end

Yes, you can create a process with the BPMN model API.
BpmnModelInstance modelInstance = Bpmn.createExecutableProcess()
  .name("BPMN API Invoice Process")
  .[...]
  .userTask()
    .name("Assign Approver")
    .camundaAssignee("demo")
  .userTask()
    .id("approveInvoice")
    .name("Approve Invoice")
  .[...]
  .userTask()
    .name("Prepare Bank Transfer")
    .camundaCandidateGroups("accounting")
  .serviceTask()
    .name("Archive Invoice")
    .camundaClass("org.camunda.bpm.example.invoice.service.ArchiveInvoiceService")
  .[...]
  .done();

See:

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/blob/master/bpmn-model-api/generate-process-fluent-api/README.md
https://forum.camunda.io/t/creating-models-programmatically-c8/37473/4.

